# Get Category Based On Amount Value from Date In sql

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a very simple table

```
ID| Category| Amount
------------------------
1 | Size 1  | 50000.00
2 | Size 2  | 100000.00
3 | Size 3  | 500000.00
```

I want to return category "Size 1" when the amount passed is less than or equal to 50000.00
"Size 2" when the amount passed is less than or equal to 100000.00 but greater than "Size 1"
"Size 3" when the amount passed is less than or equal to 500000.00 but greater than "Size 2"

One obvious way to do this is to simply use if conditions but this is just an example , there can be any number of categories. So I cant just hardcode it.

Answer (score 2):

See the code below

```
public class TesteStackOverflow
{
    public TesteStackOverflow(decimal amout)
    {
        List<testTable> list = new List<testTable>();
        list.Add(new testTable { Id = 1, Category = "Size 1", Amount = 50000 });
        list.Add(new testTable { Id = 2, Category = "Size 2", Amount = 100000 });
        list.Add(new testTable { Id = 3, Category = "Size 3", Amount = 500000 });


        var r = (from n in list where amout <= n.Amount select n).First();

        if(r != null)
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(r.Category);
        else
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Category not found");

    }
}

public class testTable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One simple way...

```
SELECT CATEGORY
FROM YourTable
WHERE AMOUNT = (SELECT MAX(AMOUNT)
                FROM YourTable
                WHERE AMOUNT <= YourValue)
```

Comment: +1 This seems to be the right answer. 
I have found another way by myself as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the limits In a table and then join with it.

Comment: What if do not want to create another table? Or another column

Comment: Look at Computed Columns. You could also create a view. Anyway, you will need to put the rules somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like

```
SELECT  TOP 1 *
FROM    @Table
WHERe   Amount >= @Val
ORDER BY Amount
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1dba9/5)

Comment: Can't use that, because it will give nothing when quantity is greater than all of the mentioned ones.

Comment: You did not specify that in your requirement. What whould it be if it is greater?

Comment: @Arbaaz what do you want to return when the quantity is greater?

Answer (score 0):

```
if not exists(
SELECT  TOP 1 *
FROM    tbl_TicketSizeMst
WHERe   Amount >= @amt
ORDER BY Amount
)
begin
select top 1 * FROM  tbl_TicketSizeMst
end
else 
begin
SELECT  TOP 1 *
FROM    tbl_TicketSizeMst1
WHERe   Amount >= @amt
ORDER BY Amount
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a view with the following definition:

```
; WITH x AS (
  SELECT id
       , category
       , amount
       , Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY amount) As sequence
  FROM   your_table
)
SELECT x.id
     , x.category
     , Coalesce(prev.amount, 0) As lower_amount
     , x.amount As upper_amount
FROM   x
 LEFT
  JOIN x As prev
    ON prev.sequence + 1 = x.sequence
```

This view will return a resultset like so:

```
id category lower_amount upper_amount
-- -------- ------------ ------------
1  Size 1        0.00     50000.00
2  Size 2    50000.00    100000.00
3  Size 3   100000.00    500000.00
```

Then you can query this view like so:

```
SELECT category
FROM   that_view
WHERE  @your_value >  lower_amount
AND    @your_value <= upper_amount
```

Answer (score 0):

tell me for which sample data it do not work (where it fail)

```
Declare @t table(ID int, Category varchar(50), Amount float)
insert into @t
select 1 , 'Size 1', 50000.00 union all
select 2 , 'Size 2' , 100000.00 union all
select 3 , 'Size 3'  , 500000.00

Declare @input float=50000


select id,category ,amount from @t a
where a.Amount-@input=(select  min(a.Amount-@input) from @t a where a.Amount-@input>=0 )
```